# Failure to install tidyverse package in R: "namespace 'tidyselect' 1.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.1 is required"

Tags: r, installation, tidyverse

I'm trying to install "tidyverse" package in R using install.packages("tidyverse"), but it returns the following error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/franc/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
tidyverse  1.3.1  1.3.2             FALSE

installing the source package ‘tidyverse’

tentando a URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 702514 bytes (686 KB)
downloaded 686 KB

* installing *source* package 'tidyverse' ...
** package 'tidyverse' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'tidyselect' 1.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/franc/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/tidyverse'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiqAHM6\downloaded_packages’
```

For some reason the installation doesn't work. I've also tried using install.packages('tidyverse', type = 'binary'), but it installs an older version that is incompatible with some packages I have to use.

Comment: Did you try ```install.packages ('tidyverse', dependencies = TRUE)```?

Comment: Did it ask you if you wanted to install from source? It looks like you may have said "yes" to that. It would probably install fine if you say "no" instead. Otherwise restart R so no packages are loaded, and then update tidyselect first: `install.packages("tidyselect")`. That should install the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. but I had to install tidyselect using type = 'binary'. After that, I've managed to successfully install tidyverse.